# Liferay Service is not overriding journalArticle is not calling restoreArticleFromTrash?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

This method is not calling while restore article from recycle bin.

```
@Override
public void restoreArticleFromTrash(long groupId, String articleId) throws PortalException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(":::::::::::::restote article from the trash::::::::::::");
    super.restoreArticleFromTrash(groupId, articleId);
}
```

Comment: you need to provide more information. Where do you have this method, how is the component registered...

Comment: Are you trying to do a service wrapper for the JournalArticleService? Can you post the entire class?

Comment: Have added the serviceWrapper class

Answer (score 0):

`JournalArticleTrashHandler` calls the `JournalArticleLocalService`'s `retoreArticleFromTrash` method. I'm assuming this is the entry point into the Journal Article's service layer for the action you're taking in the portal. Because the call is directly to the Local Service, I think you need to create a service wrapper for `JournalArticleLocalService` rather than `JournalArticleService`.

Comment: i have checked with JournalArticleLocalService  as well.. even though i will not able override the   retoreArticleFromTrash..  It is Bug in liferay 7

Answer (score -1):

Every method is  calling except restoreArticleFromTrash.
Is any other way.

**Below added the full class file**

@Component(service = ServiceWrapper.class)

public class CustomJournalArticleServiceWrapper extends JournalArticleServiceWrapper {

```
public CustomJournalArticleServiceWrapper() {
    super(null);
}


    @Override
public JournalArticle addArticle(long groupId, long folderId, long classNameId, long classPK, String articleId,
        boolean autoArticleId, Map<Locale, String> titleMap, Map<Locale, String> descriptionMap, String content,
        String ddmStructureKey, String ddmTemplateKey, String layoutUuid, int displayDateMonth, int displayDateDay,
        int displayDateYear, int displayDateHour, int displayDateMinute, int expirationDateMonth,
        int expirationDateDay, int expirationDateYear, int expirationDateHour, int expirationDateMinute,
        boolean neverExpire, int reviewDateMonth, int reviewDateDay, int reviewDateYear, int reviewDateHour,
        int reviewDateMinute, boolean neverReview, boolean indexable, boolean smallImage, String smallImageURL,
        File smallFile, Map<String, byte[]> images, String articleURL, ServiceContext serviceContext)
        throws PortalException {

    return super.addArticle(groupId, folderId, classNameId, classPK, articleId,
            autoArticleId, titleMap, descriptionMap, content, ddmStructureKey, ddmTemplateKey, layoutUuid,
            displayDateMonth, displayDateDay, displayDateYear, displayDateHour, displayDateMinute,
            expirationDateMonth, expirationDateDay, expirationDateYear, expirationDateHour, expirationDateMinute,
            neverExpire, reviewDateMonth, reviewDateDay, reviewDateYear, reviewDateHour, reviewDateMinute,
            neverReview, indexable, smallImage, smallImageURL, smallFile, images, articleURL, serviceContext);
            }


            @Override
public JournalArticle updateArticle(long groupId, long folderId, String articleId, double version,
        Map<Locale, String> titleMap, Map<Locale, String> descriptionMap, String content, String ddmStructureKey,
        String ddmTemplateKey, String layoutUuid, int displayDateMonth, int displayDateDay, int displayDateYear,
        int displayDateHour, int displayDateMinute, int expirationDateMonth, int expirationDateDay,
        int expirationDateYear, int expirationDateHour, int expirationDateMinute, boolean neverExpire,
        int reviewDateMonth, int reviewDateDay, int reviewDateYear, int reviewDateHour, int reviewDateMinute,
        boolean neverReview, boolean indexable, boolean smallImage, String smallImageURL, File smallFile,
        Map<String, byte[]> images, String articleURL, ServiceContext serviceContext) throws PortalException {


        return super.updateArticle(groupId, folderId, articleId, version, titleMap,
            descriptionMap, content, ddmStructureKey, ddmTemplateKey, layoutUuid, displayDateMonth, displayDateDay,
            displayDateYear, displayDateHour, displayDateMinute, expirationDateMonth, expirationDateDay,
            expirationDateYear, expirationDateHour, expirationDateMinute, neverExpire, reviewDateMonth,
            reviewDateDay, reviewDateYear, reviewDateHour, reviewDateMinute, neverReview, indexable, smallImage,
            smallImageURL, smallFile, images, articleURL, serviceContext);
            }




@Override
public JournalArticle moveArticleToTrash(long groupId, String articleId) throws PortalException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("::::::::::move article to the trash:::::::::::::");
    return super.moveArticleToTrash(groupId, articleId);
}



@Override
public void restoreArticleFromTrash(long groupId, String articleId) throws PortalException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(":::::::::::::restote article from the trash::::::::::::");
    super.restoreArticleFromTrash(groupId, articleId);
}

}
```

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.